# "Promised to be exciting, but ended being boring"

Tags: idiom-requests

> Although it promised to be exciting, *it ended being boring/dull/useless*.

Any idiom for the above phrase?

Answer (score 3):

It ended not with a bang but a whimper. (a slight adaptation of T S Eliot's famous stanza).

Comment: Though not an idiom, Shakespeare's immortal words come to mind:   "[Life] is a tale/
Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury/
/Signifying nothing."

Comment: TS couldn't hold a candle to WS.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a slew of idioms for this. The first few I thought of were these:

> [It fizzled out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fizzle+out).
>   [It petered out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peter).
>   [It ended with a fizzle](http://theowlunderground.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/the-old-year-ended-with-a-fizzle/).  [Not sure that this is really an idiom, but it's close.]
>   [It was a dud](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dud).
>   [It bombed](http://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/bomb). (def 2)

Comment: All sort of fireworks (or not-fireworks). ***Damp squib*** falls into that category too.

Answer (score 1):

A single word suffices.

> [underwhelming](https://www.google.com/search?q=underwhelming)

is a quasi-non-standard neologism since the 1970's. It was originally created as a snarky backformation for the other dierection from 'overwhelming', but it has since become accepted. For example,

> It was a wasted evening at the symphony. The premier of the wunderkind's latest piano concerto was underwhelming.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to something not living up to the hype, you could say:

> All Sizzle, No Steak.

or

> It failed to deliver.