# What is an idiom for great start but cheap/pathetic ending?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I have to write an article which I want to end with an idiom, but unfortunately, I can't think of any.

**Background:**
A speaker of our "Event management committee" has spoken really nice about Humanity, being Human and Nature, but in the end, he used some poor examples which contradicted what he said and against Nature, humanity. He ended an amazing speech, with poor metaphor/analogy in support of castism, skin color, etc.

Comment: One idiom that contrasts a strong beginning with a weak end is _starts with a bang, ends with a whimper_. For example: https://www.oregonlive.com/business/2018/01/dow_starts_day_with_a_bang_end.html and https://www.globalvillagespace.com/what-began-with-a-bang-ended-in-a-whimper-javed-hassan/

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Promised to be exciting, but ended being boring"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105719/promised-to-be-exciting-but-ended-being-boring)

Comment: Yes, it answers my question, but can it more than just a whimper. :) Person should get that it was really a shitty talking about that.

Comment: The beginning of the speech was great, but _it went downhill from there_.

Comment: *It held great promise, but (failed to deliver / fell flat / fell flat on its face).* I suspect the question is too open ended as it stands, because you haven't provided an actual example sentence. We are all considering an entire sentence, rather than just a concluding phrase. Please provide an example sentence, with a space into which what you want should be placed.

Comment: I had a great answer in mind, but it fizzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ... and ended up being a damp squib.
2. Let’s not mistake dying embers for being the spark of a revolution.

Answer (score 1):

Japanese proverb: Dragon's head serpent's tail

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could say your speaker **snatched defeat from the jaws of victory**. From The Free Dictionary:

> [**snatch defeat from the jaws of victory**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snatch+defeat+from+the+jaws+of+victory) (idiom): To fail, lose, or be defeated despite the appearance that one would be victorious, especially due to a mistake, error, or poor judgment. (An ironic reversal of the more common "snatch victory from the jaws of defeat.")

You could also say your apeaker **blew it**. From Lexico:

> **[blow](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/blow)** (informal with object): Completely lose or miss (an opportunity). Example sentence: ‘I spent the remainder of the night staring at the ceiling, trying to figure out how I could have blown such a perfect opportunity.’

You could say your speaker **crashed and burned**. From Lexico:

> **[crash and burn](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/crash_and_burn)**: Come to grief or fail spectacularly.